# Minecraft cursor freezes when I hover over bottom right of chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Sometimes when I'm on my friend's server, when my I put my cursor to the bottom right 4 cells of a chest, my cursor kind of freezes until I move out of those cells. I can't move the items in those cells either. I have also experienced the whole right hand side of my inventory being like this before. Another point to add is that when the cursor is frozen on the cells, the item name is not shown. Also, I have experienced an empty crafting table crafting book. This only happens on my friend's server. The issue seems random. My friend has tried deleting the playerdata for me from the server but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you make a screen recording of this (not a video of your monitor)? Also, do you have any of these programs installed? https://minecraftirc.net/support-articles/known-incompatible-software/

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "The cursor freezes on the bottom right 4 cells on a chest." What do you mean by cells also? Do you mean pixels? A video would be really helpful.